# qsort comparison: why const void *?

Tags: c, pointers, int, quicksort, qsort

I have been studying C programming from a book called "The Practice of Programming" by Kernighan and Pike. Based on the material in this book I have written a small program to sort an array of integers given on the command line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSIZE 30

char *progname;
int arr[MAXSIZE];

int icmp(int *, int *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    progname = argv[0];
    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [int ...]\n", progname);
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; argc > 1 && i < MAXSIZE; i++, argc--) {
        arr[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);
    }
    int n = i;
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(*arr), icmp);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    exit(0);
}

int icmp(int *p1, int *p2) {
    int v1 = *p1;
    int v2 = *p2;
    if (v1 < v2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (v1 == v2) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Yes, my little program seems to work and I am quite happy with it. However, my implementation differs from the one given in the book, which does not seem to sort integers correctly. The authors define icmp() as:

```
int icmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    int v1, v2;
    v1 = *(int *) p1;
    v2 = *(int *) p2;
    if (v1 < v2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (v1 == v2) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

What's the deal? My version also throws a warning from gcc:

```
warning: passing argument 4 of 'qsort' from incompatible pointer type
```

But, the qsort with the correct pointer type is not correctly sorting my ints! Very confused here. If anyone can enlighten me I will be very grateful.

Comment: Passing a function pointer of the wrong type triggers undefined behaviour when qsort tries to call the function.

Comment: What do you mean "the qsort with the correct pointer type is not correctly sorting my ints"?

Comment: you should probably use the original argc-1 instead of sizeof(arr*) in the qsort arguments.

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331: The code uses `sizeof(*arr)` (not `sizeof(arr*)`).  The third argument to `qsort()` is the size of each element.  The size of the integers does not depend on the number of arguments — it is fixed at `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(arr[0])` or `sizeof(*arr)`, which is correct, therefore.

Comment: When I adapt the code so I can test both comparator functions in a single invocation of the program, they both 'work' correctly, and the data is sorted correctly by both.  I had to use a sledgehammer cast to avoid a compilation warning with your `icmp` (the cast was `(int (*)(const void *, const void *))icmp`), but that was all.  What makes you think the `const void *` version isn't working correctly?

Comment: Mr. Leffler, my sincere apologies. Apparently I had written the code incorrectly in the first place and tried to hack a "quick fix" without checking my work. The authors' solution does in fact work; I had experienced the numbers sorted in an incorrect order which I did not attempt to characterize at the time. Thanks for your insight and effort on this question, sir. Will request deletion...

Answer (score 7):

> qsort comparison: why const void *?

If you check the prototype of `qsort`, you'll find:

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size,
        int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

The parameter type of the `compar` function is `const void *` as you noticed.

- It's `void *` because `qsort` is supposed to sort generic type, not just `int`. You can sort array of `double`, array of `string`, array of `struct`, and so on.
- It's `const void *` to avoid accidental changes to the data that the pointer is pointing to (within that `compar` function). This is just a typical safety measure of the keyword `const`.